# Pass in a range of cells as variable values to a single query?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have two sheets, sheet1, and sheet2. Column E of sheet2 contains a quantity and column K contains a text string (i.e. a key). Multiple rows in sheet2 contain the same text string with different quantities.

On sheet1 column B, I have a list of text strings. For each text string, I want to query sheet2 and sum up all the quantities in its E column where the value in the K column matches the text string.

Currently, I need x queries where x is the number of text strings in column B of sheet1.

Each current query in sheet1 looks like this:

Query in sheet1 cell A1 using text string in B1 of sheet1

```
 =SUM(
  QUERY(
    'sheet2'!$A$2:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'sheet2'!O",'sheet2'!P1)), "select  E where K="""&B1&""""
  ))
```

Query in A2 using text string in B2 of sheet1

```
 =SUM(
  QUERY(
    'sheet2'!$A$2:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'sheet2'!O",'sheet2'!P1)), "select  E where K="""&B2&""""
  ))
```

and so on...

Cell P1 of sheet2 contains the number of non-zero rows in sheet2

This works well, but the problem is that sheet2 contains 200,000 rows.
I have around 100 text strings to search for, so I am currently using 100 queries, each of which looks at 200K rows x 15 columns = 3 Million cells

Understandably it takes a long time for the sheet to update as all these queries re-run when sheet2 is updated.

Is it possible to consolidate all of these queries to one? In other words, tell the formula "I want you to perform the sum-query using each cell in the range B1:B100 as the variable x for K=x in the query and place the results in cells A1:A100 respectively"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in some cases putting it into array may boost a bit the performance:

```
={SUM(QUERY('sheet2'!$A$2:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'sheet2'!O", 'sheet2'!P1)), 
      "select E where K="""&B1&""""));
  SUM(QUERY('sheet2'!$A$2:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'sheet2'!O", 'sheet2'!P1)), 
      "select E where K="""&B2&""""))}
```

however, too many `QUERY` functions should be avoided to prevent the halt. the best performance belongs to `DGET` and alternatives include `FILTER` and `SUMIF`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Could you elaborate more on the performance improvements of DGET vs Query? How meaningful is the improvement?

Comment: DGET function is the one and only database function in GS. So if you have a structured data you can use it for vertical lookup. It can improve your spreadsheet performance compared to VLOUKUP or QUERY.
Also, In DGET function the Criteria (lookup column) position is not important. It can be from any column. But in VLOOKUP it should be the first column. The only downside of DGET is that it cant handle duplicates in dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This I hope as your single query, B8 must be change to the last row in sheet1

```
=arrayformula(vlookup({Sheet1!B1:B8},QUERY(Sheet2!A1:K,"select K, sum(E) where K<>0 group by K "),2,false))
```